# How can you programatically export a BizTalk ESB itinerary?

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.1

How can you programatically export a BizTalk ESB itinerary, as opposed to the "right click on the diagram and select Export Model" approach?

I've checked in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1\Bin`, but can't see any tool to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the itinerary is stored inside the SQL Server database as XML.

You can pick it from the db "EsbItineraryDb" using C# by its name, from the "dbo.Itinerary" table.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't strictly true ... it's only the case if you've used the ExportAll and the itineraries ModelExporter is set to Database Itinerary Exporter, so the itinerary is written to the SQL table. And it's not an answer to my question as it's not a way to programatically export the XML